# Mock DB.withConnection in play scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, anorm

I have a service class in our app that looks something like this:

```
class ChecklistCreationScheduler @Inject()(jobScheduler: JobScheduler,
                                           dBApi: DBApi,
                                           futureChecklistRepository: FutureChecklistRepository) extends ClassLogger{
def scheduleSingleFutureChecklistJob(futureChecklistId: Muid): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"Preparing to schedule one time future checklist job for future checklist id '${futureChecklistId.uuid}'")
    val db = dBApi.database("default")
    logger.info("Database" + db)
    db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      logger.info("Connection" + connection)
      ...
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to create a unit test where connection is mocked. What I did is injected `dbApi` and mocked that:

```
"ChecklistCreationScheduler#scheduleSingleFutureChecklistJob" should {
      "schedule a single job through a scheduler" in {
        val futureChecklistId = Muid.random()

        val jobScheduler = mock[JobScheduler]

        val connection = mock[Connection]
        val DB = mock[Database]
        DB.getConnection returns connection

        val dbApi = mock[DBApi]
        when(dbApi.database("default")).thenReturn(DB)

        val futureChecklistRepository = mock[FutureChecklistRepository]
        doReturn(Option.empty).when(futureChecklistRepository).getById(futureChecklistId)(connection)

        val chCreationScheduler = new ChecklistCreationScheduler(jobScheduler, dbApi, futureChecklistRepository)

        chCreationScheduler.scheduleSingleFutureChecklistJob(futureChecklistId) must throwA[UnexpectedException]
      }
    }
```

Everything compiles fine and database on this line is my mocked object:
`val db = dBApi.database("default")`

However, it does not go any further. The only thing this method basically returns nothing.
What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks,

Comment: You can have a look at the test framework (used by Anorm itself to unit test persistence function): https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte/tree/10m-anorm-tutorial ; See [documentation](http://acolyte.eu.org/).